# Android service causes memory problems

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I’m experiencing some trouble with my Android application. In the application I have a long running task for syncing the user data from the Azure server to the local SQL after the user has successfully logged in. Therefore I designed a Service, that binds with an activity when launched, to inform the user how much longer the task will take.

The data the app has to copy from online database to local SQLlite is quite large, this causes the memory to spike very high, because the AzureService & SqlService must request pretty big lists of data. It goes from +- 30mb to 60mb ram. Once all this is done, the activity in charge for the syncing stops the service and a **SecondActivity** is launched.

My problem is that even after the **FirstActivity** ( handles the sycing ) has killed everything ( the connection, the service, the activity itself… ) the memory doesn’t drop in the **SecondActivity**. I’ve tried different tricks to get it to drop ( punch the ‘cause gc’ in the monitor, open other apps that require memory ) but it doesn’t seem to work. I have no idea what I might have leaked in the **FirstActivity** that causes the memory to stay high in the **SecondActivity**, as far as I can see trough debugging, everything gets destroyed what needs to be destroyed. *What have I done wrong?*

**FirstActivity**:

```
[Activity (Label = "Dvit.Apps.MemoryManager", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class FirstActivity : Activity
    {
        BirdyService _service;
        IServiceConnection _connection;
        TextView _serviceOutput;
        Boolean _isBound = false;

        public FirstActivity ()
        {
            _connection = new SyncServiceConnection (this);
        }

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            Button btnStartService = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);
            Button NextPage = new Button (this);
            _serviceOutput = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtServiceOutput);
            NextPage.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (WindowManagerLayoutParams.MatchParent, 100);
            NextPage.Gravity = GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal;
            NextPage.Text = "Next Page";
            NextPage.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                UnboundService();
                this.Finish();
                StartActivity(typeof(SecondActivity));
            };

            (btnStartService.Parent as LinearLayout).AddView (NextPage);

            btnStartService.Click += delegate {
                BindService ();
                Intent syncLoginInfoIntent = new Intent (this, typeof(BirdyService));
                syncLoginInfoIntent.PutExtra ("commandType", "LoginSync");
                StartService (syncLoginInfoIntent);
            };
        }

        void BindService ()
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Bind service");
            base.BindService (new Intent (this, typeof(BirdyService)), _connection, Bind.AutoCreate);
            _isBound = true;
        }

        void UnboundService ()
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Unbinding service");
            if (_isBound) {
                ((SyncServiceConnection)_connection).OnDisconnect ();
                base.UnbindService (_connection);
                _isBound = false;
            }
        }

        void HandleSyncFeedback (object sender, BirdyService.SyncProgressEventArgs e)
        {
            this.RunOnUiThread(() =>{_serviceOutput.Text += "\n" + e.Extra;});
        }

        protected override void OnDestroy ()
        {
            base.OnDestroy ();
            Console.WriteLine ("FirstActivity Destroyed!");
             _connection = null;
            _serviceOutput = null;
        }

        class SyncServiceConnection: Java.Lang.Object, IServiceConnection
        {
            FirstActivity _self;

            public SyncServiceConnection (FirstActivity self)
            {
                _self = self;               
            }

            public void OnServiceConnected (ComponentName className, IBinder service)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("~~CONNECTING SERVICE!!!~~");
                _self._service = ((BirdyService.SyncBinder)service).Service;
                _self._service.SyncProgressEvent += _self.HandleSyncFeedback;
            }

            public void OnDisconnect ()
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("~~DISCONECTING SERVICE!!!~~");
                if (_self._service != null) {
                    _self._service.SyncProgressEvent -= _self.HandleSyncFeedback;
                    _self._service = null;
                }
            }

            public void OnServiceDisconnected (ComponentName className)
            {   

            }
        }
    }
```

**SecondActivity**:

```
[Activity (Label = "Dvit.Apps.MemoryManager", Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class SecondActivity : Activity
{
    int count = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it

    }

    protected override void OnDestroy ()
    {
        base.OnDestroy ();
        Console.WriteLine ("SecondActivity Destroyed!");
    }
}
```

**The Service**:

```
[Service (Enabled = true)]
public class BirdyService:Service
{
    IAzureService _azureSvc;
    ISqlService _sqlSvc;
    ISyncService _syncSvc;
    IGlobalSettings _settings;
    AndroidSqlteConnection _connection;

    #region Service 'IsSyncing?' Checkers

    private Boolean _syncLoginSync = false;



    public Boolean IsServiceSyncing {
        get {
                if (_syncLoginSync == true)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;               
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public class SyncProgressEventArgs:EventArgs
    {
        public SyncProgressEventArgs ()
        {
            this.Progress = 0;
            this.IsCompleted = false;
        }

        public bool IsCompleted {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Extra{ get; set; }

        public Int16 Progress {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<SyncProgressEventArgs> SyncProgressEvent;


    #region Binder => communication between starting activity & service

    private IBinder binder;


    public class SyncBinder:Binder
    {
        BirdyService _service;

        public SyncBinder (BirdyService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

        public BirdyService Service {
            get{ return _service; }              
        }
    }

    public override IBinder OnBind (global::Android.Content.Intent intent)
    {
        return binder;
    }

    #endregion

    public BirdyService () : base ()
    {
        binder = new SyncBinder (this);
    }

    public override void OnCreate ()
    {
        base.OnCreate ();

        var appContext = this.ApplicationContext as MemoryManagerApplication;

        _settings = appContext.GlobalSettings;
        _azureSvc = new AzureService (new MobileServiceClient (_settings.AzureMobileServiceUrl, _settings.AzureMobileServicePassword));
        _connection = new AndroidSqlteConnection ();
        _sqlSvc = new SqlService (_connection);
        _syncSvc = new SyncService (_azureSvc, appContext.WebApiClient, _sqlSvc, _settings);
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand (global::Android.Content.Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        if (intent != null) {
            var command = intent.GetStringExtra ("commandType");
            var keepAlive = intent.GetBooleanExtra ("keepAlive", false);

            Console.WriteLine ("~~>SERVICE TASK RECEIVED COMMMANDNAME: " + command + "<~~");

            switch (command) {
            case "LoginSync":
                {
                    LoginSync (intent, keepAlive);
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    #region LoginSync

    private void LoginSync (global::Android.Content.Intent intent, bool keepAlive = false)
    {
        new Task (async () => {
            try {
                var progressEventArg = new SyncProgressEventArgs ();
                _syncLoginSync = true;
                _settings.IsSyncingOrganisations = true;

                progressEventArg.Extra = "Fetching master data...";
                progressEventArg.Progress = 10;

                if (SyncProgressEvent != null)
                    this.SyncProgressEvent (null, progressEventArg);

                await _syncSvc.SyncMasterData (true);

                var requestUserInfoFragment = await Authenticate (progressEventArg);

                _settings.IsSyncingOrganisations = false;
                progressEventArg.Extra = "Completed!";
                progressEventArg.Progress = 100;
                progressEventArg.IsCompleted = true;

                if (SyncProgressEvent != null)
                    SyncProgressEvent (requestUserInfoFragment, progressEventArg);

                _syncLoginSync = false;

                if (!IsServiceSyncing && !keepAlive)
                    this.StopSelf ();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                _syncLoginSync = false;
                //_Logger.Trace (ex.Message);
                _settings.IsSyncingOrganisations = false;

                if (!IsServiceSyncing)
                    this.StopSelf ();

                throw;
            }
        }).Start ();

    }

    async Task<Boolean> Authenticate (SyncProgressEventArgs args)
    {
        try {

            args.Extra = "Fetching user...";
            args.Progress = 30;
            if (this.SyncProgressEvent != null)
                this.SyncProgressEvent (null, args);

            Account account = await _azureSvc.AccountByGoogleId (_settings.LoginUserId);
            if (account != null) {
                var party = await _azureSvc.GetItemById<Party> (account.PartyId);

                args.Extra = "User found, initializing user data ...";
                args.Progress = 50;
                if (this.SyncProgressEvent != null)
                    this.SyncProgressEvent (null, args);

                _sqlSvc.Insert<Party> (party);
                _sqlSvc.Insert<Account> (account);

                args.Extra = "User found, fetching organisation data...";
                args.Progress = 50;
                if (this.SyncProgressEvent != null)
                    this.SyncProgressEvent (null, args);
                //Fetch organisations
                await _syncSvc.SyncPartyInitData (party.Id, true, true);

                //Fetch appointments & orders
                args.Extra = "Organisation data completed, fetching party data...";
                args.Progress = 80;
                if (this.SyncProgressEvent != null)
                    this.SyncProgressEvent (null, args);

                await _syncSvc.SyncPartyDetailData (party.Id);

                //do not request user info
                return false;

            } else {

                //FILL IN ACCOUNT
                account = new Account ();
                Party party = new Party ();
                party.Id = Guid.NewGuid ().ToString ();
                account.Id = Guid.NewGuid ().ToString ();
                account.IdentityProvider = _settings.LoginPlatform;
                account.IdentityToken = _settings.LoginUserId;
                account.PartyId = party.Id;
                account.InfoProvider = _settings.UserInfo.RawData;
                account.LoginName = _settings.LoginUserId;

                //FILL IN PARTY 
                bool requestUserInfoFragment = false;

                if (_settings.UserInfo != null) {

                    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (_settings.UserInfo.FirstName)) {
                        party.FirstName = _settings.UserInfo.FirstName;
                    } else
                        requestUserInfoFragment = true;

                    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (_settings.UserInfo.LastName)) {
                        party.LastName = _settings.UserInfo.LastName;

                    } else
                        requestUserInfoFragment = true;

                    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (_settings.UserInfo.Email)) {
                        party.Email = _settings.UserInfo.Email;
                    } else
                        requestUserInfoFragment = true;

                }

                party.LocalIsNew = true;
                account.LocalIsNew = true;

                _sqlSvc.Insert<Party> (party);
                _sqlSvc.Insert<Account> (account);


                if (!requestUserInfoFragment) {
                    args.Extra = "Adding new users to the server";
                    args.Progress = 80;
                    if (this.SyncProgressEvent != null)
                        this.SyncProgressEvent (null, args);

                    await _syncSvc.SyncAllFromType<Party> ();
                    await _syncSvc.SyncAllFromType<Account> ();

                }
                //ELSE sync in newuserfragment


                return requestUserInfoFragment;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public override void OnDestroy ()
    {
        base.OnDestroy ();
        Console.WriteLine ("Destroying BirdyService");
        _connection.Close ();
        _connection = null;
        _azureSvc = null;
        _sqlSvc = null;
        _syncSvc = null;
        _settings = null;
    }

}
```

Comment: There's a lot of I can see here that is contributing to your problem. Give me a couple of hours while I build a coherent and comprehensive answer. Basically: Closures *can* create context leaks so don't use anonymous methods for button handlers and call Dispose() at the very end of an activities `OnDestroy()` call.

Comment: I wouldn't mind mailing you my project to you, but i need to be sure of your good intentions, i dont want my azure development data to get messed up :) Contact me at christophe@dvit.eu if this could spare you some time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of your issue is that you don't know what content is still being referenced, and what's referencing it.

It should be straightforward to track down where memory is allocated with the tools inside Android Studio. [Memory Profiling 101](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P--rg1o7Cz4&index=32&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE) walks through how to use memory monitor, allocation tracker and heap-viewer to find specific problems.

Really, these tools give you very clear insight into where your memory is going. I'd start there and snoop out what your second activity still has handles to.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, turn on Strict mode to detect activity leaks by adding this to the OnCreate of your apps first activity:

```
StrictMode.SetVmPolicy (new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder ().DetectAll ().PenaltyLog ().Build ());
```

This will dump out a warning into logcat every time more than 1 activity instance of a type is detected. It'll look like this:

```
[StrictMode] class md5962cfe7bc03e689322450e055e633b77.FirstActivity; instances=2; limit=1
[StrictMode] android.os.StrictMode$InstanceCountViolation: class md5962cfe7bc03e689322450e055e633b77.FirstActivity; instances=2; limit=1
[StrictMode]    at android.os.StrictMode.setClassInstanceLimit(StrictMode.java:1)
```

The next thing is to sever the peer object connection for your activity:

```
    protected override void OnDestroy ()
    {
        base.OnDestroy ();
        base.Dispose ();
        GC.Collect (GC.MaxGeneration);
    }
```

The `base.Dispose ()` breaks the peer object connection between a C# object and a Java Vm object. http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/garbage_collection/#Disposing_of_Peer_instances

In general, this should be enough fix the leaks for your sample. You can also go a step further and dispose then null all objects in the Activity that derive from Java.Lang.Object. For instance:

```
    protected override void OnDestroy ()
    {
        button.Dispose ();
        button = null;

        base.OnDestroy ();
        base.Dispose ();
        GC.Collect (GC.MaxGeneration);
    }
```